# Is there any sense to declare static global variable as inline?

Tags: c++, static, c++17, global, inline

Consider, global variable (not static class member!) is declared in the header file:

```
inline static int i{};
```

It is valid construction for several compilers that I tested, and experiments demonstrate that several distinct objects will be created in different translation units, although it is also declared as inline (it means that only one instance of that variable must exist in the program). So, has `static` keyword more priority than `inline` in that case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So, has static keyword more priority than inline in that case?

Pretty much. `static` has an effect that interferes with `inline`. The C++ standard [states that](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.inline#6)

> ... An inline function or variable with external linkage shall have
>   the same address in all translation units.

And the `static` qualifier imposes *internal linkage*, so the single address guarantee does not have to hold. Now, a name with internal linkage in different translation units is meant to denote different object in each TU, so getting multiple distinct `i`'s is intended.

All in all, the `static` negates the `inline`. And there is no point to having a `static inline` variable over a plain `static` one.

Comment: What is the reason to not forbid that declaration? Any complications in grammar parsing for compilers?

Comment: @user3514538 - No. Probably no one considered it an actual problem when first adding it. And it isn't some huge problem that warrants the standardization process now.

Comment: So does that also mean that functions defined as `static inline` are a thing of the past when it comes to modern C++?

Comment: @303 - `static inline` is a C artefact, born out of the different way C treats functions declared `inline`. C++ always treated `inline` functions the way I described here.

Comment: I wouldn’t say “the single address guarantee does not have to hold”: internal-linkage declarations simply declare different entities (perhaps with different types, or one and not the other might even be a template or so), so there is no (single) variable to which the same-address rule could apply.

Comment: A naive question: Will `const static inline std::string` variable in a header of global/namespace scope improve performance? Eg: every transaction unit has its own copy which doesn't change and if the executable is too big, which might make accessing the `const inline` less efficient. I just use `std::string` as an example of a non primitive type to disregard "use `std::string_view` or `const char *` and get it inlined instead".

Comment: @LouisGo - I don't see why it would be more efficient. In all arches I know, all those constants will be parked in the same section of the executable ("in a TU" is only relevant to source code locality and access), and each will need to be initialized dynamically along with allocation. Might as well have just one (by ditching the static).