# Why can a static inline variable have several different addresses?

Tags: c++, c++17

I don't understand why a variable defined as `inline static` can have more than one address when the keyword `inline` means that there can only be one definition of my variable.
[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) says the following about inline variables:

> It has the same address in every translation unit.

This does not seem to be true for `inline static` variables.
Does the `static` keyword override the `inline` keyword or am I missing something?

Here's the test I did:

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include "io.h"

int main() {  
  if(&is_value != &get_is_value())
    printf("inline static variable from main and io have different addresses.\n");
  if(&i_value == &get_i_value())
    printf("inline variable from main and io have the same address.\n");
  if(&s_value != &get_s_value())
    printf("static variable from main and io have different addresses.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

*io.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

inline static int is_value = 42;

inline int i_value = 43;

static int s_value = 44;

int& get_is_value();

int& get_i_value();

int& get_s_value();
```

*io.cpp*

```cpp
#include "io.h"

int& get_is_value() { return is_value; }

int& get_i_value() { return i_value; }

int& get_s_value() { return s_value; }
```

*output*

```bash
inline static variable from main and io have different addresses.
inline variable from main and io have the same address.
static variable from main and io have different addresses.
```

Clearly, the `static inline` variable has 2 different addresses depending on the translation unit.

Can you explain this to me, please?

Comment: `cppreference.com says the following about inline variables:` - does it though? It literally says *"An inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage **(e.g. not declared `static`)** has the following additional properties:"*.

Comment: So the `inline` keyword does nothing in this case?

Comment: Shouldn't the third message be `"static variable from main ..."`? And AFAIK the `inline` in `inline static` is meaningless. What should its meaning even be if `static` means "this entity is only available in this translation unit"?

Comment: `static` in namespace/global scope means **internal linkage**; i.e. anything declared with that keyword is visible only to the current TU. `inline` OTH enables immediate definition of the object/function. A `static inline` specifier on an objects enables it to be both `static` and defined in the same line as its declaration. For namespace/global/ function scope this brings no special advantage. But in class scope - where `static` object has external linkage, this prevents ODR violation and simpler code.

Comment: [As I told someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58101044/817643), static inline variables at namespace scope are a pointless construct. I used to not consider them harmful, but I think compilers ought to start warning about them. The confusion they cause people can lead to misuse and odr violations.

Comment: The `static` keyword has different behavior in different contexts. At the namespace scope it means internal linkage which means every TU has its own instance of that variable or function so the inline keyword loses its power. But inline static at a class scope is pretty useful.

Comment: @Red.Wave but aren't "inline" member functions (defined in the class definition) implicitly `inline`?

Comment: @chrysante: Yes, mostly, but that doesn’t actually matter like people think it does: the class definition, duplicated in every relevant translation unit, already declares one type so of course it has just one of each member function.

Comment: @DavisHerring but the definition must be unique. If `class` scoped `static` object is not declared `inline` nor immutable (`const` or `constexpr`), then it must be defined and initialized in exactly one CPP file; it cannot be initialized in a public header.

Comment: @Red.Wave: Of course, but I was writing about member functions, not data members.

Comment: @DavisHerring sorry! I was thought you are following OP's question on variables. `inline` keyword on functions doesn't do much.